# How to install WST in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

Can you install the  web standard tools (WST) without having to install the Web Tools Platform (WTP) in eclipse ? If yes how can I do that ?

Comment: help->eclipse marketplace. But it's much easier and safe to just download WTP. good luck